# Working with excel in java

Tags: java

Hello guys i have tried editing and working with excel in java, but kept getting errors after doing everything as below:

```
package writer;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import jxl.*;
import jxl.write.*;
import jxl.write.Number;


public class Writer {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        try{

   String fileName = "‪‪‪C:\\Users\\Valentine\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Writer\\src\\Workbook.xls"; 
    WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(fileName));
    WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1", 0);
    //Adding A Label
    Label label = new Label(0,0,"A label record");
    sheet.addCell(label); 
    Number number = new Number(0,1,3.1459);
   sheet.addCell(number);
   workbook.write();
   workbook.close();

    }catch (WriteException e){
```

This is the error an getting

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: ‪‪‪C:\Users\Valentine\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Writer\src\Workbook.xls (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at jxl.Workbook.createWorkbook(Workbook.java:301)
    at jxl.Workbook.createWorkbook(Workbook.java:286)
    at writer.Writer.main(Writer.java:17)
C:\Users\Valentine\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

I appreciate your help. thanks

Comment: Does C:\Users\Valentine\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Writer\src\Workbook.xls file exist?

Comment: yes @RomanPuchkovskiy, it exits, thats where the excel file is

Comment: Assuming that the file actually does exist on that path, try a properly encoded java path, like this:

"/Users/Valentine/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Writer/src/Workbook.xls"  Windows paths (with back-slashes) generally work, but this is worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the excel file before running the program. Even though the exception is `FileNotFoundException`, if you have the file opened, and you run the program, it throws that exception which is a little misleading. Your program JVM process tries to lock the file which was locked by MS Excel program, so the exception is understandable